# Spouse H4B VISA has been scheduled. What if my contract got terminated before Interview date?

Tags: usa, h1-visa

I am working in USA with H1B VISA. My H1b Sponser is my employer and I am working for their client projects on contracts.

My wife is travelling to India(Our Home Country) next week. Since her VISA is expired she has to go to Interview and get renewed.  But my contract extension is next month. My wife VISA Interview has been scheduled next month.

What will happen if my contract with my client didn't get extend and need to look for another client. Did it impact my wife VISA extension decision any way?

Answer (score 3):

> What will happen if my contract with my client didn't get extend and
>   need to look for another client. Did it impact my wife VISA extension
>   decision any way?

Most likely the decision will be negative. Since you don't have a valid H1b sponsor - you'll be out of status, and your wife won't be eligible for H4 status.

Legally speaking, if you're terminated you're out of status and are expected to leave the country. There's no "looking for another client". I know many people (especially from India) abuse the USCIS lack of enforcement, but you're playing with fire here (especially with the current political climate).

Comment: My H1b Sponsor does't change. I am not changing my employer/my H1B sponsor. Only we in fact my employer loosing project from client. Does it have any impact on my spouse H4 visa approval decision?

Comment: @Babu are you still getting paid?

Comment: Yes. I will get paid

Comment: @Babu then the troubles your employer is having are irrelevant.

Comment: ,what does that mean? I didn't understand, would you mind to explain it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are A, your employment agency is B, and their clients are C, D, and E.

USCIS  considers your employment contract to be with B. As long as B hasn't fired you, you are good.

Now, it might be the case that since B doesn't have new contracts after losing C+D+E, then they might fire you. But you don't know that to be absolutely the case and there's no reason to bring up hypotheticals when you or your wife renew.

However, if B has given you notice or actually fired you, you need to tell USCIS this.